# Using multiple values for span in geom_smooth in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use different `span` values for different groups when generate `geom_smooth` graph. 
The following code as an example to assign 2 values to 2 groups.

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt,  y = mpg, color = factor(am)))+
  geom_smooth(span = c(0.2, 0.8))
```

It does not work. I have also tried to add a variable in the data frame. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `span` values in `method.args`. But it's an argument to `stat_smooth`, not `geom_smooth`.

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = wt,  y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
  stat_smooth(geom = "smooth", 
              method = "loess", formula = y ~ x,
              method.args = list(span = c(0.2, 0.8)))
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to change the values `list(span = c(0.2, 0.8))` but it appears that changing values doesn't make difference to the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this & this worked too:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = wt,  y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
            geom_smooth(span = 0.6)

#Output: warning & plot
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

I think one cannot pass on vectors like that. In that case, use the method explained by Rui Barradas.